# How to correct determine ReflectionMethod::getPrototype

Tags: php, reflection

Completely unclear how to determine whether a method has a prototype or not.

**Example**:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public function foo()
    {
    }
}

$refl = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');

var_dump($refl->getMethod('foo')->getPrototype());
```

**Output for PHP 5.1.2 - 5.5.5**:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
>   'Method MyClass::foo does not have a prototype'...

I would like to implement something like `bool ReflectionMethod::hasPrototype( void )` for my ReflectionMethod wrapper.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPrototype` is documented to throw if a prototype does not exist, so it's straightforward to convert that to a boolean:

```
public function hasPrototype()
{
    try {
        $this->getPrototype();
        return true;
    }
    catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Phil: I agree. But future-proofing at the cost of a single byte sounds like a no-brainer to me.

Comment: Just realised you're doing some kind of `ReflectionMethod` extension which could be anywhere. Good idea in that case though I'd just import (`use`) it at the top :)